# Как обработать webhook от Microsoft Bot Connector?

Tags: php, skype, бот

Приветствую.

Люди добрые, кто может русским языком объяснить, что происходит на последнем этапе этой схемы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда бот получает само сообщение которое ему отправил пользователь?

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что ты имеешь ввиду, то что на картинке это процесс аутентификации  REST API, оно не обрабатывает сообщения, они нужны например для того что бы послать в чат (если ты знаешь его номер) сообщение

Вообще работа Бота для node.js выглядит так (пример почти из документации):

```
    var restify = require('restify');
    var builder = require('botbuilder');
    var server = restify.createServer();
    server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
       console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
    });

    // Create chat bot
    var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
        appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
        appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
    });
    var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
    server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

    //=========================================================
    // Bots Dialogs
    //=========================================================

    //Обработаем команду /
    bot.dialog('/', function (session) {

        session.send('Твой ID'+ session.message.user.id);
        session.send('Твое Имя '+ session.message.user.name);

        console.log("Current message address",session.message.address);
    });
```

Насколько  я помню, address это и есть тот путь (id чата) который ты сможешь потом использовать что бы послать что то в ответ  через REST API.

А session.send ответит в чат немедленно

Т.е. по идеи разработчиков Skepy ты можешь создать обработку маршрутов и в автоматическом режиме отвечать на запросы пользователя, для всего остального, например оповещений о новостях или чем то таком, ты должен использовать RestAPI

Comment: Благодарю за правку, у меня не хватило рейтинга для вставки изображения. Я пишу на php, но если этого фрагмента достаточно для **получения** сообщений от пользователя, попробую js. Я, возможно, не очень ясно изложил свою мысль - проблем с **отправкой** сообщений никаких нет, использую готовую библиотеку с github. Вот с получением затык. Неделю перечитываю доки по #botframework, а внятного объяснения **когда** прилетает тот самый POST именно с контентом (а не просто с заголовками, для авторизации) найти не получается.

Comment: @ penishands сперва внимательно почитай как бота создать и подключить, когда это только появилось, кроме как на azure по-моему нигде нельзя было обработчик бота размещать, но я точно не помню это было почти год назад.